# Unpivot a table in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql-9.4, postgresql-9.5, unpivot

I need to unpivot a table in PostgreSQL. The first dataset is what I have, the second is what I want:

[image]

Below is my schema with sample dataset:

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/3f45c/1

My understanding is that you may have to use JSON functions to accomplish this in PostgreSQL, as it doesn't have an `unpivot` function as some other SQL variants do. I'm open to other solutions, though.

Comment: If I'm interpreting your info correctly, your first data  set is what you have, and your second is what you want. There's no JSON data in either - why do you want to unpivot using JSON, rather than simply unpivot? What do you have in mind when you say "unpivot using JSON"?

Answer (score 2):

Unpivot can be done using an array and unnest:

```
select s.state, s.city, 'item'||t.i as items, t.item
from state1 s
  cross join lateral unnest(array[item1, item2, item3]) with ordinality as t(item,i);
```

Online example: http://rextester.com/VPDDN96018